# Is this possible using Reactive Framework?

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive

I have a list of objects in my C# 4.0 app. Suppose this list contains 100 objects of student class. Is there any way in Reactive Framework to parallel execute 10 objects each at a time?

Each student object runs a method which is some what time consuming for about 10 to 15 seconds. So the first time through, take the first 10 student objects from the list and wait for all the 10 student objects to finish its work and then take next 10 student objects and so on until it completes the full items in the lists?

1. I have a `List<Student>` with 100 count.
2. First take 10 items from the lists and calls each object's long run method in parallel.
3. Receives each objects return value and update the UI [subscription part].
4. Next round starts only if the first 10 rounds completes and releases all the memory.
5. Repeat the same process for all the items in the lists.
6. How to catch the errors in each process ??
7. How to release each student object's resources and other resources from memory ?
8. Which is the best way to do all these things in Reactive Framework ?

Answer (score 1):

This version will always have 10 students running at a time.  As a student finishes, another will start.  And as each student finishes, you can handle any error it had and then clean it up (this will happen before the next student starts running).

```
students
    .ToObservable()
    .Select(student => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            // do the work for this student, then return a Tuple of the student plus any error
            try
            {
                student.DoWork();
                return { Student = student, Error = (Exception)null };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return { Student = student, Error = e };
            }
        })))
    .Merge(10) // let 10 students be executing in parallel at all times
    .Subscribe(studentResult =>
    {
        if (studentResult.Error != null)
        {
            // handle error
        }

        studentResult.Student.Dispose(); // if your Student is IDisposable and you need to free it up.
    });
```

This is not *exactly* what you asked since it does not finish the first batch of 10 before starting the next batch.  This always keeps 10 running in parallel.  If you *really* want batches of 10 I'll adjust the code for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am very new to RX and trying to study it. You all are very helpful. In this solution, i see it takes only 10 students and after that 10 student finishes, can't see any code for taking next 10 students [like batches] until it covers 100 students. The student list collection contains total 100 students. Since doing all the 100 students running in parallel may cause out of memory exception, my plan was to run the students in batches of 10. Please help.

Comment: the `.Merge(10)` does this.  Think of it like a bouncer at a bar.  It only allows 10 students in at a time.  As soon as one of those students is done and leaves, there are only 9 students left in there, so `Merge` will let another one in.  It will keep doing this until all 100 students have been processed.

Comment: Thanks the help. It really takes 10 students @ a time and take another 10 next time. When it takes a batch of 10, is there any method in Rx to run those 10 students can run parallel. The above solution is waiting for each batch completing and then only it calls the subscribe. In subscribe, I have another to fire some event to update the UI in the wcf client. But waiting for the complete exection of each batch kills the time. I am looking for something faster way in RX. Is there any way to run the members in a batch parallel ?

Comment: This is doing that.  Add this code to your program and add some print statements at the start and end of of `student.DoWork()` and then run it and you will see from the print statements that it keeps 10 students running at all times.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt....

```
var students = new List<Student>();
{....}
var cancel = students
    .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
    .Window(10)
    .Merge(1)
    .Subscribe(tenStudents =>
    {
        tenStudents.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)
            .Do(x => DoSomeWork(x))
            .ObserverOnDispatcher()
            .Do(tenStudents => UpdateUI(tenStudents))
            .Subscribe();               
    });
```

Comment: Pretty simple really. Window(10) converts the work into chunks of 10. Merge(1) work on a single thread. Convert the 10 students into an inner observable. Do, erm...do some work. ObserveOnDispatcher() go back to the UI thread on the next bit. Do...umm...work on UpdatingUI. Finally Subscribe on the inner observable. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thanks again Aron. My doubt was how to release each 10 student object resources. Your explanation was very helpful and many thanks for it. I am worried about out of memory issues. Pls help me.

Comment: Once again Aron, if it is not a UI thread, what will replace for observeondispatcher ???

Comment: In that case if you don't need to marshal back to the UI thread you can drop the ObserveOnDispatcher()

Comment: As for memory issues, the point of a memory managed environment is that memory is GCed. The Observerable should clean up after themselves after they raise OnCompleted. No promises...

Comment: This isn't running the 10 students in parallel.  It takes a group of 10 students and runs the group serially.   Which means you are really running all 100 students serially

Comment: Ah...you are correct when thinking about it...let me try and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

This to me sounds very much like a problem for TPL. You have a known set of data at rest. You want to partition up some heavy processing to run in parallel and you want to be able to batch process the load.

I don't see anywhere in your problem a source that is async, a source that is data in motion, or a consumer that needs to be reactive. This is my rationale for suggesting that you use TPL instead.

On a separate note, why the magic number of 10 to be processed in parallel? Is this a business requirement, or potentially an attempt to optimize performance? Normally it is best practice to allow the TaskPool to work out what is best for the client CPU based in the number of cores and current load. I imagine this becomes ever more important with the large variations in Devices and their CPU structures (Single Core, Multi Core, Many Core, low power/disabled cores etc).

Here is one way you could do it in LinqPad (but note the lack of Rx)

```
void Main()
{
    var source = new List<Item>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){source.Add(new Item(i));}

    //Put into batches of ten, but only then pass on the item, not the temporary tuple construct.
    var batches = source.Select((item, idx) =>new {item, idx} )
                        .GroupBy(tuple=>tuple.idx/10, tuple=>tuple.item);

    //Process one batch at a time (serially), but process the items of the batch  in parallel (concurrently).
    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
        "Processing batch...".Dump();
        var results = batch.AsParallel().Select (item => item.Process());
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            result.Dump();
        }
        "Processed batch.".Dump();
    }
}


public class Item
{
    private static readonly Random _rnd = new Random();
    private readonly int _id;
    public Item(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get {return _id;} }

    public double Process()
    {
        var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        string.Format("Processing on thread:{0}", threadId).Dump(Id);
        var loopCount = _rnd.Next(10000,1000000);
        Thread.SpinWait(loopCount);
        return _rnd.NextDouble();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Item:{0}", _id);
    }
}
```

I would be interested to find out if you do have a data-in-motion problem or a reactive consumer problem, but have just "dumbed down" the question to make it easier to explain.